# With Firebse v9 Auth , my displayName does not appear after my submit, I have to reload the app to see it (React-Native Expo)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-authentication

When I submit my form my displayName is taken into account but I have to reload the app so that it can appear on my home screen (it does not appear after the first redirect). I want it to be loaded directly during the first redirect, after the submit...

Can you help me please :) Thank you

**My authContext function for the submit :**

```
 const isSignUp = async (email, password, displayName) => {
        const {user} = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(authentication,email, password)
        await updateProfile(user, {
            'displayName': displayName
        })
    }
```

**My Submit Function :**

```
const onSignUpPressed = async (data) =>{
    console.log(data)
   await isSignUp(email, password, displayName )
    .then((res) => {
      // console.log(res)
  
      })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      switch(error.code) {
        case "auth/email-already-in-use" : alert("Un compte utilise déjà cet email");
        break
      }
    })
    .finally(() => mounted.current)
  }
```

My render component

```
return (
    // <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
        <ImageBackground 
          source={image} 
          resizeMode="cover" 
          imageStyle={{opacity:.05}}
          style={styles.imageBackground}
          >
          <SafeAreaView style={styles.signupContainer}>
              <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Créer un compte</Text>
              </View>
              <CustomInputText 
                  name="pseudo"
                  placeholder="Pseudo"
                  control={control}
                  rules={{
                    required: "Veuillez entrer un pseudo",
                    minLength : {value: 3, message: "3 caractères minimum"},
                    maxLength : {value: 20, message: "20 caractères maximum"},
                    }}
                  />
              <CustomInputText 
                  placeholder="Email"
                  name="email"
                  control={control}
                  rules={{
                    required: "Veuillez entrer un email",
                    pattern: {
                      value: /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
                      message: "Veuillez entrer un Email valide",
                      },
                    }}
                  />
              <CustomInputPassword 
                  placeholder="Mot de passe"
                  name="password"
                  control={control}
                  secureTextEntry
                  rules={{
                    required: "Veuillez entrer un mot de passe",
                    minLength : {value: 8, message: "8 caractères minimum"},
                  }}
                  isShowIcon={true}
                  />
              <CustomInputPassword 
                  placeholder="Confirmer le mot de passe"
                  name="confirm-password"
                  control={control}
                  secureTextEntry
                  rules={{
                    required: "Veuillez entrer un mot de passe",
                    validate: value => value === password ? true : "Le mot de passe ne correspond pas"
                  }}
                  isShowIcon={true}
                  />

                <CustomButton
                  text={"Créer un compte"}
                  onPress={handleSubmit(onSignUpPressed)}
                  />

                <SocialSignInButton />

                <CustomButton
                  text={'Déja un compte ? Se connecter'}
                  onPress={onSigneIn}
                  type={'SECOND'}
                  />
                <Text style={styles.textConditions}>
                  En vous inscrivant, vous acceptez les <Text style={styles.textConditionsLink} onPress={onTermOfUser}>Conditions d'Utilisation</Text> et la <Text style={styles.textConditionsLink} onPress={onPrivacyPolicy}>Politique de Confidentialité</Text>, incluant l'<Text style={styles.textConditionsLink} onPress={onCookiesUtilisationst}>Utilisation de Cookies.</Text>
                </Text>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </ImageBackground>

  // </ScrollView>
    
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for rendering the component?

Comment: @DavidScholz like this ?